# pyside/cython using lambda in slots produces error

Tags: lambda, callback, pyside, cython

I already read a lot on the web including the post "Understanding lambda in python and using it to pass multiple arguments" but there are still some things that i don't understand regarding using lambda in pyside slots and passing arguments, hopefully somebody can help :-)

I have a pyside QWidget with multiple slots like this one here:

`self.push_register.clicked.connect(lambda: self.register(name))`

and the function goes like:

`def register(self, name):
    register code here`

So that is all some basic stuff and it works like expected.

Now I created a cythonized .so file. So far almost all code still works like expected, however I am struggling with slots when I try using lambda and passing some arguments. I suddenly get the error

`TypeError: lambda8() takes no arguments (1 given)`

This error appears in different locations.

I tried changing the slot to using lambda x: like the following:

`self.push_register.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.register(name))`

on some locations that worked but in some slots it didn't work. Then I read about using functools.partial as an alternative to lambda and this worked again on some slots but not on all. I am now stucked and don't understand how to use pyside slots with passing arguments for cythonized files. In plain .py files everything works by simply using lambda.

When can I use a simple callback like

`self.push_register.clicked.connect(lambda: self.register(name))`

when do i use:

`self.push_register.clicked.connect(lambda x: self.register(name))`

and when do I use:

`self.push_register.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.register, name))`

Is there a receipt when to use what? And is there a way to use only one receipt for all callbacks? Can anybody help? Thank you

UPDATE: So the following works fine:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7f97d7bd61f2652f1e3e

Comment: Update: I managed to get rid of some other TypeError: `lambda8() takes no arguments (1 given)` by adding keyword arguments to the called function, so: def register(self, name, *args)

Comment: I think this would benefit from a minimum complete example - i.e. a short PySide application that uses a lambda. It'd be quite a bit of work for someone else to build one to investigate this.

Comment: `connect(lambda *args: func())`